# Logo application removed still present

Tags: 20.04, appmenu, logo

I have deleted some applications in the Ubuntu 22.04, but the application 'logos' are still persistent. When I click on them, nothing happens. I suppose that the logos of ghost applications are default placeholders stored in the system information.

You can see a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot application]

Comment: There is something wrong with how you uninstalled those applications. How did you proceeded ? And do you remember how you installed those applications ? This happens when the Icon is removed but the `.desktop` file of your application remains.